# Filling in for missing latest data with last available data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables, one (`market_cap_data`) with `month_end_date, id, market_cap` fields:

```
month_end_date    id         market_cap
2012-12-31       123456        5000
2011-12-31       123456        4000
```

and a second table (`start_date_table`) with `month_end_date, id, start_date` fields:

```
month_end_date    id         start_date
2011-12-31       123456        1980-12-31
```

I want to combine the two tables but the start_date_table data ends a year before the market_cap_data table.  I want to fill the latest data where the start_date_table doesn't have data using the most recent start_date.  For example, instead of an outside join like:

```
month_end_date    id         market_cap    start_date
2012-12-31       123456        5000           NULL
2011-12-31       123456        4000          1980-12-31
```

I want it to look like

```
month_end_date    id         market_cap    start_date
2012-12-31       123456        5000          1980-12-31
2011-12-31       123456        4000          1980-12-31
```

Tried a bunch of different things but can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you provide us a fiddle:  sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    m.month_end_date,
    m.id,
    m.market_cap,
    CASE 
        WHEN s.start_date IS NOT NULL THEN s.start_date
        ELSE (SELECT MAX(s2.start_date) FROM start_date_table s2 WHERE s2.id = m.id)
    END AS start_date
FROM market_cap_data m
LEFT JOIN start_date_table s
    ON m.id = s.id
    AND m.month_end_date = s.month_end_date
```

Comment: Very elegant!  This is a great solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you would benefit from a case statement, **this is not tested as I don't have a fiddle to validate against**

```
create function get_latest_date_from_table(varchar(100) table_name  returns Date
(  
    return select max(date) from #table_name
)  

create procedure modify_null_dates_for_marker  
(  
   max_date Date;  
   max_date = get_latest_date_from_table('table');
    select
         foo,  
         bar
    CASE WHEN start_date IS NULL
        THEN  max_date
        ELSE  start_date END AS start_date
    FROM table  
)
```

This should give a method to set the `null` columns correctly.

Comment: Thanks Woot4Moo!  I did a slight variation but this concept worked perfectly.

Comment: @eqsf please inform me what the variation was, so I can inform future visitors of it.